# How to include jsp file with logic in java/spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I wonder if is is a way to include jsp file like: in page.jsp:

```
include: header.jsp
```

but with a logic of this file, I'm a front-end developer so in Angular i can create component that contains html template and js file with logic inside, and by using component name like

```
<my-header></my-header>
```

i can #1 include html code, and #2 automatically invoke logic of this template,
I heard about

```
<jsp:include>
```

but probably it can't do what I want.

Comment: Angular is frontend and JSP are compiled when server is started. Why are you combining angular and JSP? By logic, you mean business logic implemented in Java or you meant client side logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Tiles framework to achieve this.

https://tiles.apache.org/framework/

Comment: I read about them in book "Spring in action", but the author didn't mention nothing about passing a logic, could you tell me more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf ( or Tiles ) are better bets than JSP.  As a general rule you shouldn't include much logic unrelated to whats absolutely necessary for display purposes in the front end.